# Where are my contacts on Skype for Web?

Tags: skype-for-web

I'm using Windows 10 AU, and I have installed **Skype for desktop**. And then, that version crashes frequently, and in mid of a chat I need close and reopen.

I have tried then **Skype Preview** for Windows 10, and looks unstable and crashes too, but silently, and then I miss a lot of important messages from customers (not really why I can receive notifications on "**Skype for android**").

But I hate chat on Android... Even on WhatsApp I prefer WhatsApp Web version!

My last hope is **[Skype for Web](https://web.skype.com)**. I signed up with my Skype account but for my surprise, not Contacts are displayed! The link "Add Friends" ask my phone number or Google, LinkedIn or Yahoo! account, but I want my **actual Skype Contacts from my Skype account**!. The same contacts that I get from when I connect from another 3 versions.

Am I doing something wrong or I need "start a new life" in the web version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

The problem is, I have a Skype account and a Microsoft account with the same email, and that accounts are not "linked" (I dont know about this). when you use a Google account, by example, your email is the same to all services... but then, Microsoft simply have 2 account systems, independent...

What I did:

1. Log out from Skype for Web
2. On Skype for Desktop, click Skype -> Profile -> Edit My Profile
3. In profile, near of your Skype ID, click on "Manage" link
4. You will be redirected and logged in https://secure.skype.com/portal/account/settings
5. Here you will see cleary "Skype Name" and "Linked Microsoft Account" are different things
6. Click on "My Account" link on top right of the page. You will be redirected to https://secure.skype.com/portal/overview
7. Finally, you can click on link Skype for Web (beta) (redirected for https://web.skype.com/?intcmp=accountweb-_-uktrybeta) and enjoy the correct account